# How to create view of files upladed to webform with appropriate webform fields data?

Tags: views, webforms, files

In my webform user can attach multiple files. What I am struggling with is creating a view of files (so line per file, not line per webform submission) with webform files and appropriate webform data.
I created a view of files and tried both *File usage* relationship and *Webform submissions (fid)* relationship but none of these provide me with the submission data, although I can see webform fields in the view fields, so I can add them in my view, but they are not being populated with data.